Why am I not able to get a window based application in auto-py-to-exe?
I have a python app that I wanted to make into a .exe app. I am using auto-py-to-exe for this, and I just upgraded the auto-py-to-exe to version 2.45.0.
Now whenever I try to make my file into a window based app, I get the error below that this could not be done as the file contains a virus or malware, and my anti-virus software flagged it as a Trojan, but whenever I try to make the same .py file into a .exe file that is console based, it gives no errors, and converts it, and the anti-virus also has no problems with it.
The auto-py-to-exe was working fine before the update.
P.S. I tried with other simpler code and its giving the same message.
This is the command that I am being shown:
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "<Icon Path Here>"  "<File Path Here>"
and this is the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 36, in pywin32error
yield
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 209, in BeginUpdateResource
return _resource._BeginUpdateResource(filename, delete)
#            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 39, in check_null
raise make_error(function, function_name)
OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 132, in package
run_pyinstaller(pyinstaller_args[1:])
#     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 215, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
#     ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 70, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
#     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1252, in main
build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
#     ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1192, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
#     ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp76jncox0\Chopsticks v.3.3.1.spec", line 19, in <module>
exe = EXE(
pyz,
#     ...<14 lines>...
icon=['C:\\Programs\\Programs\\Python_Programes\\My_Inventions_and_Copys\\Inventions\\Chopsticks_Game\\Pics\\logo.ico'],
#     )
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 658, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
#     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
#     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 771, in assemble
self._retry_operation(icon.CopyIcons, build_name, self.icon)
#     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 1033, in _retry_operation
return func(*args)
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 212, in CopyIcons
return CopyIcons_FromIco(dstpath, [srcpath])
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 144, in CopyIcons_FromIco
hdst = win32api.BeginUpdateResource(dstpath, 0)
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 208, in BeginUpdateResource
with _pywin32error():
#          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\contextlib.py", line 162, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(value)
#     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
File "C:\Programs\Sources\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 40, in pywin32error
raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (225, 'BeginUpdateResourceW', 'Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.')```


See the error messages, especially: "OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software."

But I scanned the source file too, and its not giving any flags as a virus. Only when I try to convert to .exe with "window based" selected, am I getting this error. And before updating auto-py-to-exe, the same code was not getting this error.

Scanning the source file makes no difference. The message is telling you that the virus checker examined the executable code and thinks it looks like a virus. I have had a  similar issue with other code in the past. You could switch off the checks while you build your code, or try running on a different system.
